# What is the "flickering lamp" connected to?

Tags: the-witness

There is a flickering lamp at the lake, which is emphasised at the [ending video](https://youtu.be/gBjb33x7npo?t=419). It is flickering in the video, and can be both active and passive (permanently off) in the game itself.

What exactly do you need to do so the lamp will start/stop flickering in the game itself?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

As per my observation, it has three states (Steam version 1.057M).

- At the beginning, it's almost sunk, meaning you haven't completed the game.
- After getting into the flying elevator at the end and restarting over (you have to load the last save data to see), the statue rises above the water and the lamp is flickering.
- After 100% completion (523 +135 +6, plus all audio logs), the lamp stops flickering and dies out.

  [image]

I am unsure about the second bullet, but I am *extremely confident* that the last point is correct, because I spent 3 hours tracing my last puzzle and my last audio log, and when I found them both, the lamp stopped flickering (I found the puzzle first, but the lamp was still flickering after solving it, it's the audio log that finally made the lamp went out).